# How to draw a splunk chart depicting no of occurrences for different strings?

Tags: search, logging, splunk

I  want to draw a splunk chart and I have following strings in my logs:

```
"Request id: 552"
"Request id: 223"
"Request id: 365"
"Request id: 552"
"Request id: 552"
"Request id: 223"
```

I want to create a chart with x axis values as the request ids (552,223,365) and y axis values as number of occurrences of these request ids. What splunk search query would work?

Answer (score 0):

try this query, fill the index details in both main search and sub search
assuming the field-name as log,

```
 index=...  | append[search index=... | eval req_id=ltrim(log,"Request id: ")] 
| stats count(log) as req_id_count by req_id | table req_id,req_id_count
```

this should work.